# How do I prevent this bash script from appending a date to backups it makes?

Tags: bash, sh

This is a minecraft init-script. I am trying to get it to not append the date to the backup zip file or tar file, and the date is given from the "datepath" function. However, I don't want to completely remove the datepath function, as it is needed for other functions. I'm not familiar with bash scripts, is there anyone familiar with bash who can help? It shouldn't take long.

```
mc_world_backup() {
    get_worlds
        today="" # If you don't want a folder for each day change to today=""
    for INDEX in ${!WORLDNAME[@]}
    do
        echo "Backing up minecraft ${WORLDNAME[$INDEX]}"

        case "$BACKUPFORMAT" in
            tar)
                path=`datepath $BACKUPPATH/${WORLDNAME[$INDEX]} .tar.bz2 .tar.bz2`
                as_user "tar -hcjf $path $MCPATH/${WORLDNAME[$INDEX]}"
                ;;
            zip)
                path=`datepath $BACKUPPATH/${WORLDNAME[$INDEX]} .zip .zip`
                as_user "zip -rq $path $MCPATH/${WORLDNAME[$INDEX]}"
                ;;
            *)
                echo "$BACKUPFORMAT is no supported backup format"
                ;;
        esac
    done
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to duplicate whatever `datepath` does, except for appending a date.  So it would help to know what `datepath` does.

Comment: is the result of `path=datepath...` a path like `/data/2012/03/09/myLogfile.zip` ? OR `/path/to/logfiles/myLogFile.20120309.log.txt.zip` (or similar). Not everyone knows the internal structures of minecraft, so a editing your question with details like 'I have this format xxxx and I need this format yyyy' will also help. Good luck.

Comment: why are two copies of the file suffix passed to datepath?

Answer (score 1):

Based on new info in the discussion under the other answer:

If we have a variable `$path` which contains `"world_03/07/2012.tar"`, we can do this to convert it to `"world.tar"`:

```
path="${path%_??/??/????.tar}.tar"  # quotes not needed if path has no spaces
```

The `_??/??/????.tar` pattern matches the suffix `_03/07/2012.tar` and other similar ones. You can make it more strict by restricting to digits: `_[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].tar`. This is probably unnecessary since the string comes from a function with a known, uniform output.

Answer (score 0):

why are two copies of the file suffix passed to datepath? Would it accept empty strings for these? If so, would the date then just be the suffix of the path string? IN that case it could be removed and at the same time replaced with a suffix, with a shell parameter expansion like

```
path=`datepath ... "" ""`
# remove a suffix portion matching <SUITABLE_PATTERN> and append .zip.
path=${path%<SUITABLE_PATTERN>}.zip
as_user "zip ..."
```

To know how to remove the date, an example would be required. The ${VAR%PAT} suffix removal syntax works with shell globs. For instance ${VAR%[0-9]?} will remove a suffix like 3X from the string, but not XY (because X is not a digit).

Comment: I'll tell you what I don't want. I don't want it like this: world_03/07/2012.tar. Instead I want it like this: world.tar. Could you tell me where I would insert that in my code? Like I said, I'm not familiar with bash scripting, this is someone else's init script.

Comment: As soon as you touch it, it's your script. :)

Comment: I worded that wrong. It's not my code, as in it wasn't written by me, but it's being used by me.